# Can't get any event while Protected Mode In IE is ON

Tags: c#, winforms, internet-explorer, events, protected-mode

I'm writing an IE add-on (ToolBar) with Winform and I need to get the mouse position and keyboard key press

And I don't get any Windows event while the IE is on Protected mode,

Even the `protected override void OnLostFocus(EventArgs e)` is not working!

Is there a way to get Events from IE while in Protected mode?

Without the protected mode **EVERYTHING** is working fine!

*Please don't reference me to this article:* [**Understanding and Working in Protected Mode Internet Explorer**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb250462%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Did you even read [Understanding and Working in Protected Mode Internet Explorer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb250462%28VS.85%29.aspx) ?

Comment: yeah I already read that, And I want to try something else other than open a new application as a broker to fetch this data